# Umbraco.TagQuery get tags from current page

Tags: tags, umbraco

I would like to display **currentpages** **tags** by using a TagQuery. I wish it was as easy as

```
var tagList = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetAllContentTags(CurrentPage)
```

What's an easy approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags should just be a property on CurrentPage? e.g.

```
CurrentPage.tagsPropertyName.ToString().Split(',');
```

I'd use the strongly typed stuff though, as that's a bit easier to read and less prone to weird casting errors than the dynamics stuff.

```
Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("tagsPropertyName").Split(',');
```

You could even write a property converter to make it all a bit neater: http://www.theoutfield.co.uk/blog/2013/04/strongly-typed-property-values-using-property-editor-value-converters-in-umbraco

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the tags for your page using the following:

`var tagList = Umbraco.TagQuery.GetTagsForEntity(CurrentPage.Id);`